# Execute javascript function with 'this' keyword as parameter in WebBrowser C#

Tags: javascript, c#, browser, this

I need to execute a javascript function in WebBrowser C# like this:

```
Social(this,5000)
```

that is in a element like this:

```
<div id="id1" class"class1" onclick="social(this,5000)";>Click</div>
```

but parameter 'this' refers to that specific id and class(or sth else i don't know what).

using this code doesn't work:

```
var obj=new object[2];
obj[0]="this" or this(as keyword);
obj[1]=5000;
webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("social",obj);
```

how should i send the refered object to the function?

what should i do?

Edit : I have problems by sending 'this' as parameter

Comment: The param this refers the div because it is calling the function social. I don't understand what object you want send to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution finally, 'this' in this particular situation refers to 'id1' and instead of this in function we should put 'id1'

```
var obj=new object[2];
obj[0]="id1";
obj[1]=5000;
webBrowser.Document.InvokeScript("Social",obj);
```